# Performance issue on WCF Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, console-application

There is a WCF service that is hosted in a .Net Console application. The client creates a duplex channel to the service that has a callback. It calls the service in this way:

```
var task = Task<object>.Factory.FromAsync(clientRay.Proxy.BeginCalc, clientRay.Proxy.EndCalc, lst_RaySrvcDetails, state);
```

And here is the Main method of the service Console app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     ServiceHost srvcHost = new ServiceHost(serviceInstance, uriBase);
     //
     //Here the service is hosted
     //

     while(true)
     {
        ;
     }
}
```

And the MyService.cs receives the call in the below method:

```
public IAsyncResult BeginCalc(List<MBSWaldram.DataAccessLayer.Framework.ServiceDetails> input,
                    AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
   calcInput = input;

   // Create a task to do the work
   var task = Task<object>.Factory.StartNew(this.CalcTasks, state);

   return task.ContinueWith(res => callback(task));
}
```

Now the CalcTasks method, where the actual task is run, is showing less performance compare to have it on a WCF Windows Form application. One of the reason I can think of is the way I have used while(true){;} infinite loop so that the application doesn't terminates and waits for the call from the client. Not sure this the best of doing it. For some reason I can't use Windows Form Application.

I appreciate if anyone could shed some light in why there is a performance issue here.
Thanks.

Comment: Your infinite while loop is going to cause lots of processor usage.  You should look to use one of the many synchronization options available so that your Main method waits for a notification that it should exit.

Comment: @EdT: Thanks for the reply. Could you name some of the synchronization method that wouldn't hit the performance? Is EventWaitHandle among them?

Comment: Yes, [EventWaitHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.EventWaitHandle%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) and its derivates `ManualResetEvent` and `AutoResetEvent` are among the options.  You could also kick off a `Task` to host the service and in `Main` you'd call `Wait()` on that task.  Note that these options rely on the service knowing when it should stop listening.  I'm guessing you might want something more akin to a Windows Service which you could start and stop through the service manager.

Comment: Sorry I think I didn't get your point. If you start a Task to host the service, it would stop Waiting once the service is hosted and exits the Main() method. Could you possibly provide a sample code please?

Comment: That's why I said: "Note that these options rely on the service knowing when it should stop listening" since they rely on something alerting the application (via `EventWaitHandle`, or by a `Task` completing) that it should exit. It doesn't appear like you've considered that in your design. How did you intend to stop the application? Did you plan on alerting the Service it was about to be shut down so it could do any necessary cleanup? A Windows Service application has answers for these types of situations, or you have to roll your own and come up with your own solution.

Comment: @EdT: This probably is a separate question. Yet I am not sure in using Console.Readline or EventWaitHandle options in order to wait the Main method. Do both of these methods block the current thread? And does it mean that that thread is not usable until it's resumed? Does Console.Readline merely involve IO operations, and if yes then would Console.Readline not be a better choice if the task the service is going to perform(that also in multi-threads) involves no IO operation?

Comment: What I don't understand is that, the Console.Readline doesn't seem to suspend/block the thread as the MyService.CalcTasks method, when looked through task manager, seems to take advantage of all the threads. Whereas I expected to see one of the threads to show no CUP usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while (true) {;}` is really unlucky construction. In Console application take `Console.ReadLine()` instead. The application will wait until Enter press.

Comment: Thanks. Console.ReadLine improved the pefromance. But the application terminates if any key pressed.

Comment: This is more about console application as about WCF. You can check the user input like `do { 
         Console.Write(" To close the application type 'exit'");
         line = Console.ReadLine();
      } while (line != "exit");